# creating IEnumerable from enumerators in fsharp using anonymous classes

Tags: f#, ienumerable, sequence

From a class which does not implement Enumerator I can now create one (thks Daniel)

```
   type Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Element with
     member this.GetEnumerator() = 
       (seq { for i in 0 .. this.NumElements - 1 -> this.GetElement(i) }).GetEnumerator()
```

I am looking to create an IEnumerable wrapper from it

The following works, but **is there a better way**?

(for instance, a way to **not** have to specify IEnumerable interface whose implementation can derives from IEnumerable)

```
 member this.ToEnumerableElements():IEnumerable<Element> = {
     new IEnumerable<Element> with 
        member anon.GetEnumerator() :IEnumerator<Element> = this.GetEnumerator()
        member anon.GetEnumerator() :IEnumerator  = this.GetEnumerator() :> IEnumerator
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a `ToEnumerable` method you shouldn't create a `GetEnumerator` method too. Generally, calling `GetEnumerator` directly is a code smell anyway.

```
type Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Element with
  member this.ToEnumerable() = Seq.init this.NumElements this.GetElement
```

With this method in place, you can use the `Seq` module for most operations and should never have to call `GetEnumerator` directly.

For example:

```
elmt.ToEnumerable() |> Seq.iter (printfn "%O")
```

Comment: beautiful. I have to explore the core classes better. (actually I guess one *always* learn from reading them, even at a good level of proficiency once we think we know them - which I dont yet)